# "Parse error in pattern" when implementing tree

Tags: haskell

Here is my code

```
quadtreeToPic QNode x y w avg Q4(q1 q2 q3 q4) = array ((0,0) (w-1,w-1)) (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))
```

Basically, a `Quadtree` is `x y w avg QChildren` where `QChildren` is qither `Q0` or `Q4 Quadtree Quadtree Quadtree Quadtree`.

When I do what I tried above, I get this error

```
Quadtree.hs:13:34: error: Parse error in pattern: q1
   |
13 | quadtreeToPic QNode x y w avg Q4(q1 q2 q3 q4) = array ((0,0) (w-1,w-1)) (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4])) 
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is this?

Comment: You need to add brackets around the `Q4` data constructor, so `quadtreeToPic QNode x y w avg (Q4 q1 q2 q3 q4) = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Q4` dataconstructor and the parameters are a single parameter, here, so you need to add brackets *including* the `Q4` data constructor. For example:

```
quadtreeToPic QNode x y w avg (Q4 q1 q2 q3 q4) = ...
```

Note that you can use [**`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) here instead of `concat (map ...)`:

```
... concatMap quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]
```

Comment: I get the error `Quadtree.hs:13:85: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Array (Int, Int) Word8’
                     with ‘[((Int, Int), Word8)]’
      Expected type: [[((Int, Int), Word8)]]
        Actual type: [Array (Int, Int) Word8]
    • In the first argument of ‘concat’, namely
        ‘(map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4])’
      In the second argument of ‘array’, namely
        ‘(concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))’
      In the expression:
        array
          ((0, 0) (w - 1, w - 1))
          (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))`

Comment: after I make this fix. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2719875: that's a type error: your `quadtreeToPic` is supposed to return `[((Int, Int), Word8)]]`s, but it returns `[Array (Int, Int) Word8]`?

Comment: it looks like it's a different question altogether. I asked it here, if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277522/type-errors-when-implementing-quadtree