# Type Errors when implementing Quadtree

Tags: haskell

Update:

So this is my code:

```
quadtreeToPic :: Quadtree -> Array (Int, Int) Word8
quadtreeToPic (QNode x y w avg Q0)
  | w == 1 = listArray (0,0) [avg]
  | w == 2 = listArray (0,4) [avg, avg, avg, avg]

quadtreeToPic (QNode x y w avg (Q4 q1 q2 q3 q4)) = listArray ((0,0), (w-1,w-1)) (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))
```

A `Quadtree` is either

```
QNode Int Int Int Word8 QKids
data QKids = Q0 | Q4 Quadtree Quadtree Quadtree Quadtree
```

The error I get is

```
Quadtree.hs:13:90: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Array (Int, Int) Word8’ with ‘[Word8]’
      Expected type: [[Word8]]
        Actual type: [Array (Int, Int) Word8]
    • In the first argument of ‘concat’, namely
        ‘(map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4])’
      In the second argument of ‘listArray’, namely
        ‘(concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))’
      In the expression:
        listArray
          ((0, 0), (w - 1, w - 1))
          (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]))
   |
13 | quadtreeToPic (QNode x y w avg (Q4 q1 q2 q3 q4)) = listArray ((0,0), (w-1,w-1)) (concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4])) 
   |                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I solve this? Why is `[[Word8]]` expected when by definition it should expect `Array (Int, Int) Word8`?

Comment: You probably want to change this to `w == 1 = [avg]` and `w == 2 = [avg, avg, avg, avg]`, and the type to `[Word8]`, you furthermore probably want to use `listArray` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:listArray) instead of `array` in your `quadtreeToPic`. Finally I'm not convinced that the logic is completely correct.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want the type to be `‘Array (Int, Int) Word8’`, I was wondering how to return the result in that particular format. I'll look into `listArray`. Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your solution `w == 1 = [avg]` does not use `array` or `listArray` though. How would I use it?

Comment: sorry, I realize you use a recursive approach here. You will need to "unwrap" the arrays in the recursion, or use something that is capable of "combining" two arrays then in the recursive definition.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Your solution solved a lot of the problems. Can you look at my update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's referring to the underlined subexpression:

```
concat (map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4])
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The **expected type** is the type that it should be from context, that is:

```
concat ???
```

It's what the compiler knows about what `???` must be without looking inside it.  `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` <sup>(*)</sup> takes a collection of lists and joins them all together.  So we expect to see a collection of *lists*.

The **actual type** is the type that it looks like it is when analyzing the expression "from the inside":

```
map quadtreeToPic [q1, q2, q3, q4]
```

Here we get, from `map` and the declared type signature of your function, a `[Array (Int,Int) Word8]`.  It's a collection of arrays.  But we were expecting a collection of lists from the previous step.  Thus the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Array (Int, Int) Word8’ with ‘[Word8]’
```

Perhaps you want to turn those arrays into lists using [`Data.Foldable.toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) first?

<sup>(*)</sup>Well it's actually `concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]` but I simplified for exposition.